# Highlight cell border in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, formatting

I'm trying to create a table in Google Docs.  I need a header row at the top and a similar column on the left side.  To distinguish these from the rest of the table I am trying to **embolden** the line which separates them from the rest of the table, something like the middle line below:

[image]

If I make a selection of cells, a little disclosure triangle appears in the upper right cell of the selection.  If I click on this I can select which border edges are displayed, but I can't control their formatting.  If I select the menus: Format -> Paragraph Styles -> Borders and Shading I can bold the border "under" each cell, but this winds up not actually affecting the border, but rather an area above it:
[image]

How can I just bold specific segments of table borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- select top row of your table
- click the triangle on the right of your selection
- chose a bottom row of selection to be highlighted
- click on that button with lines
- select width of the border
- done

[image: 1]

---

[image: 2]

Comment: when i tried the third step it removed the other three borders...

Comment: @Michael one border at a time...

Comment: ah ok... i discovered that I can actually click on one border at a time to select it... but when I try to do it from the pull-down it removes border.