# How can I remove shading on a line?

Tags: google-docs

**How can I remove this shading on this line?** I copied the text from another.
whenever I do that. There is a light shading behind the text.

I searched it on Google. But It did not yield helpful results.
I have already gone through these post on [webapps](http://webapps)

- [How to add an outline border to a table in Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130836/how-to-add-an-outline-border-to-a-table-in-google-docs)
- [Highlight cell border in Google Docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124335/highlight-cell-border-in-google-docs)

I know this is a noobie question. But I could solve this problem.
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

**Note: How can I improve this post?**

[image: ![Light silver background on line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select one paragraph above the paragraph in focus, the paragraph in focus and one paragraph below
2. Cut (keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>)
3. Paste as plain text (keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)
4. Apply text formatting as needed.

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. You are a genius(Google doc genius). I really appreciate the help.